# Angular error "No provider for InjectionToken ORIGIN_URL!"

Tags: angular

I am trying to make an Angular app that has ngx-translate functionality by following [this](https://medium.com/letsboot/translate-angular-4-apps-with-ngx-translate-83302fb6c10d) tutorial.

I did all the steps, but I am getting the error: "Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: No provider for InjectionToken ORIGIN_URL!
at Error (native)" and I no not know what else to try.

my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';

import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

import { ORIGIN_URL } from './constants/baseurl.constants';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http, baseHref) {
    // Temporary Azure hack
    if (baseHref === null && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        baseHref = window.location.origin;
    }
    // i18n files are in `wwwroot/assets/`
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, `${baseHref}/assets/i18n/`, '.json');
}

export const sharedConfig: NgModule = {
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        HttpModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [Http, [ORIGIN_URL]]
            }
        }),
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
};
```

my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { ORIGIN_URL } from '../../constants/baseurl.constants';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    user = {
        name: 'Arthur',
        age: 42
    };

    constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private http: Http,
        @Inject(ORIGIN_URL) private baseUrl: string) {
        translate.setDefaultLang('ro');
    }

    switchLanguage(language: string) {
        this.translate.use(language);
    }
}
```

my package.json

```
"name": "WebApplicationBasic",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "4.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/node": "7.0.18",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^2.0.5",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.29",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.1",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.1",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "npm": "^2.15.11",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "style-loader": "0.17.0",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.3.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.8",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.10"
  }
```

What am I missing?

Thank you!

---

UPDATE:

Now there are no errors, but the ngx-translate doesn't work.

For

```
{{ 'ENGLISH' | translate }}

{{ 'NORWEGIAN' | translate }}
```

I get in html ENGLISH, NORWEGIAN respectively,

the translate service doesn't work.

I have debugged the javascript code with no results...

Comment: `ORIGIN_URL` seems to be provider, but can see it specified in `providers` metadata option

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that as `ORIGIN_URL` has been used as Dependency, but doesn't seems to register in `providers` array of NgModule.

```
imports: [
    HttpModule,
    //registered dependency with `ORIGIN_URL` name
    {provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: ORIGIN_URL}
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
            deps: [Http, 'ORIGIN_URL'] //passed dependency name in `deps`
        }
    }),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
        { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
    ])
]
```

Also you have to use `'ORIGIN_URL'`(as a string) with combination of `@Inject` while injecting dependency.

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private http: Http,
    @Inject('ORIGIN_URL') private baseUrl: string) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('ro');
}
```

---

Furthermore you can get rid of `@Inject('ORIGIN_URL')` part by creating [**`OpaqueToken`**](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/05/23/opaque-tokens-in-angular-2.html) for your dependency

**shared/origin-url.service.ts**

```
import { ORIGIN_URL as url } from '../../constants/baseurl.constants';
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core'

export let ORIGIN_URL = new OpaqueToken('ORIGIN_URL');
//below is `InjectionToken` implementation
//export let API_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('ORIGIN_URL');
export const THIRDPARTYLIBPROVIDERS = { provide: ORIGIN_URL , useValue: url }
;
```

Then register this `ORIGIN_URL` inside `NgModule` metadata of `AppModule`

```
import { THIRDPARTYLIBPROVIDERS , ORIGIN_URL } from './shared/origin-url.service'

imports: [
    HttpModule,
    THIRDPARTYLIBPROVIDERS, //<-- registered provider here
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
            deps: [
              Http, 
              new Inject(ORIGIN_URL), //remove this while using `InjectionToken`
              //ORGIN_URL //<-- this will be with `InjectionToken`
            ] //passed dependency name in `deps`
        }
    }),
    //...other imports
];
```

Comment: You've got to remove quotations from `ORIGIN_URL`

Comment: @Milad no, as I registered `ORIGIN_URL` with provider name `'ORIGIN_URL'`, I'll be using `'ORIGIN_URL'` for injection token, unless I explicitly create OpaqueToken for the same, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Then it should be injected like @Inject('ORIGIN_URL') , right ? which I'm not sure if it works or not, never tried it.
As far as I know, @Inject accepts a type, not a string, but I might be wrong

Comment: So you should let the user know about that, because he might wanna update all the places that he's injected it

Comment: By the way, if this works, it'll be extremely bad practice and against the whole point of providers and Tokens, and that's why they invented InjectionTokens,

Comment: @Milad let me re-write the answer by recommend using `OpaqueToken`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150525/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-milad).

Comment: It doesn't work. It gives "Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'"

Comment: @Milad I would request you to verify my edited answer, let me know if you still see anything wrong :)

Comment: the project can be found here https://github.com/dobrinsky/AngularDefault if it helps more

Comment: I tried and I get the error  "Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'"

Comment: @AndreiDobrin could you console.log(THIRDPARTYLIBPROVIDERS) in appModule so we know what's wrong  ?

Comment: @Milad thanks mate for edit, appreciated your help :)

Comment: The weirdest thing happened: I changed the  TranslateModule.forRoot({...}) to how it was and now there are no errors, the app appears, but it doesn't work...the translation doesn't work. I get "HomeComponent.html:28 ERROR TypeError: co.switchLanguage is not a function"...I will log it

Comment: I did it and "THIRDPARTYLIBPROVIDERS" is "object Object" so it is the one that gives "Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'"

Comment: @AndreiDobrin try changing `export const THIRDPARTYLIBPROVIDERS = { provide: ORIGIN_URL , useValue: url }` to `export const THIRDPARTYLIBPROVIDERS = [{ provide: ORIGIN_URL , useValue: url }]`

Comment: @yurzui it would be great, if you can help us here. I'm struggling to get it work since morning :(

Comment: We can import decorated by `@NgModule` class or `ModuleWithProviders` type. For providers we usually use `providers` array https://github.com/dobrinsky/AngularDefault/blob/master/ClientApp/app/app.module.client.ts#L26

Comment: @yurzui sorry I missed something, can you please elaborate more. Even I would be happy to seeing your answer here. then I'll be deleting mine which seems to be wrong now

Comment: @AndreiDobrin What exactly doesn't work? For me all works great http://take.ms/1kGoo Why did you declare two tokens with the same name (`user.service.ts` and `baseurl.constant.ts`)?

Comment: If I use the solution provided by Pankaj Parkar, I get "Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'". I declared it twice because I am trying different solutions

Comment: Moreover, the json tokens that should be translated are not at all. For example, <h2> {{ 'TITLE' | translate }}</h2> appears TITLE in html