# Angular 4 No provider for InjectionToken ORIGIN_URL

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4 Server side Rendering and came across the issue where all service calls need an absolute URL.

I am attempting to use "ORIGIN_URL" as was specified in my research.

Here is my app.module:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler, Inject, InjectionToken } from 

'@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { Title }  from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { LinkService } from './../shared/page/link.service';

// Main App Root Component
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ROUTES } from './app.routes';
// Component imports
import { HeaderComponent } from './../global-components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './../global-components/footer/footer.component';
import { LogInComponent } from './../global-components/login/log-in.component';

// Provider (aka: "shared" | "services") imports
import { LoggingHttpService } from './../shared/application-error-handler/logging.http.service';

// i18n support
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

import { ORIGIN_URL } from '@nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine';

...

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient, baseHref) {
    // Temporary Azure hack
    if (baseHref === null && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        baseHref = window.location.origin;
    }
    // i18n files are in `wwwroot/assets/`
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, `${baseHref}/assets/i18n/`, '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        // put shared components here
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        LogInComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [HttpClient, [ORIGIN_URL]]
            }
        })
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        LinkService,
        // put shared services here
        LoggingHttpService,
       ...
        TranslateModule
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ...
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I am attempting to inject this ORGIN_URL into a service to get the absolute URL. 
Here is my service:

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ORIGIN_URL } from '@nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { LogEntry } from './../models/Logging/LogEntry';

@Injectable()
export class LoggingHttpService {
    private baseUrl: string;
    constructor(private http: Http, private injector: Injector) {
        this.baseUrl = this.injector.get(ORIGIN_URL);
    }

    private static readonly LOG_INFORMATION_URL: string = '/api/logging/loginformation';
    private static readonly LOG_DEBUG_URL: string = '/api/logging/logdebug';
    private static readonly LOG_WARNING_URL: string = '/api/logging/logwarning';
    private static readonly LOG_ERROR_URL: string = '/api/logging/logerror';

    logInformation(logEntry: LogEntry) {
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + LoggingHttpService.LOG_INFORMATION_URL, logEntry);
    }

    logDebug(logEntry: LogEntry) {
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + LoggingHttpService.LOG_DEBUG_URL, logEntry);
    }

    logWarning(logEntry: LogEntry) {
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + LoggingHttpService.LOG_WARNING_URL, logEntry);
    }

    logError(logEntry: LogEntry) {
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + LoggingHttpService.LOG_ERROR_URL, logEntry);
    }

}
```

I am getting the error Angular 4 No provider for InjectionToken ORIGIN_URL!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399171/angular-error-no-provider-for-injectiontoken-origin-url

Comment: Yea, that question does not have a solution. The only answer suggested breaks the application.

Comment: @David Aguirre, do you found the solution for above problem, i am also facing error `NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken in angular5`, so if you know answer, can you please share here on this thread?

Comment: In my case the issue was solved with server side code that provided the base URL. In your case I believe you are missing the service that creates the URL. If you are not missing the class, make sure the class is listed in the correct modules "providers" array. Your error is telling you that the service for ORGIN_URL is not part of the module.

Answer (score 1):

`ORIGIN_URL` and `REQUEST`  is moved  `@nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine/` to `@nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine/tokens`

You can import

```
import { ORIGIN_URL, REQUEST } from '@nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine/tokens';
```